# Visual component for user input ("commands")

Tags: web-apps, library, javascript

I'm looking for an existing library, that'd provide a visual component for "entering user commands":

- the component appears on the screen by holding a hotkey combination (for example, `Ctrl + L`),
- it's a pop-up window, expecting user input & `Enter` hit
- on `Enter`, a javascript function is called with user input passed in as an argument
- user can opt out of entering by hitting `Esc` key.

I'm happy to follow pointers towards JS code excerpts to render a simple component like this. I'm working on a prototype, no fancy design or particularly wide range of customisation options is a requirement. (Disregard the look Slack one below, it's nice but potentially too much for the prototype of app I am building at this point).

Here's a couple of screenshots of the kind of component I am looking for:

[image: AlfredApp]
[image: SublimeText 4]
[image: Slack]
[image: Algolia]

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like https://kbar.vercel.app, but in native JavaScript, e.g. not a React component.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This should be a comment or part of the question.